# Disable password complexity on Windows 2012 R2

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, windows-server-2012-r2, password-management, security-groups

I have a Windows Server 2012 R2 that is my domain controller. I want to disable the password complexity rule for a few users only.
I have created a group (called Formation) in AD to identify these domain users.
I have defined a GPO in an OU to disable the password complexity rule, and I have assigned my new group to this GPO.

I was hoping this would work, but when I go (on the same server) to manage the users in AD, I try to initialyze the password, but I still get the error message saying the password complexity rule was not followed.

I tried to run *gpupdate /force* but no success...  What else should I look for to fix this?

The password policy is a computer config and I want to apply this to users, is this part of the problem?

Comment: As Greg mentioned in his answer, you'll need to use FGPP for this. - http://www.grouppolicy.biz/2011/08/tutorial-how-to-setup-default-and-fine-grain-password-policy/

Comment: It worked, I cleaned that legacy list a bit...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using legacy password policies, those apply to the entire domain.  You may want to research [fine-grained password policies](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770394(v=ws.10).aspx).

(Note: Fine-grained password policies were originally introduced in Windows Server 2008.)

Answer (score 1):

**You need to override other GPO's**

If you have your password policy built in the domain GPO then you will need to override that GPO.  Hit the checkbox for override.

[**Here an is article on Group Policy and Precedence**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc785665(v=ws.10).aspx) which discussing what is in the title as well as howto override another group policy that is taking precedence.

**Points of Interest**

- A GPO can be enforced, disabled or both.
- Block Inheritance in an organizational unit can be set
- A GPO can have settings disabled, its computer settings disabled, or all settings disabled.

There is also this question and answer that explains howto override a GPO.

- **[How do you override a GPO with another GPO?](https://serverfault.com/q/373958/266067)**

Comment: If you vote down, please explain why...